# How to deploy botbuilder sample as Azure Function

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service

I'd like to deploy one of the dotnetcore botbuilder samples as an Azure function and point the bot service registration at the Azure function.

I've found a few posts that describe this sort of thing but they seem to refer to v3 of the SDK.

Is this possible with the v4 SDK? If so, is there a sample that demonstrates this or can you provide guidance on what changes are required to the project/code to achieve this?